# ActionCable not updating page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I'm creating a ruby app, and I'm trying to implement action cable, when a user makes a post, I want the post index to update for all users. In my channels/posts.js i have:

```
App.posts = App.cable.subscriptions.create("PostsChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log(data)
    $('#list').html("<%= escape_javascript render('list') %>")
  }
});
```

in PostRelayJob.rb I have:

```
class PostRelayJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "posts",
    post: PostsController.render(list)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

and in models/post.rb:

```
after_commit { PostRelayJob.perform_later(self) }
```

When I add a post in the server console I get:

```
[ActiveJob] [PostRelayJob] [57126ec7-b091-48fc-91aa-2f940caa9421] Performing PostRelayJob from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00000003aa10d8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://today-i-have2/Post/15>>
[ActiveJob] Enqueued PostRelayJob (Job ID: 57126ec7-b091-48fc-91aa-2f940caa9421) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000000037af000 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://today-i-have2/Post/15>>
[ActiveJob] [PostRelayJob] [57126ec7-b091-48fc-91aa-2f940caa9421] Performed PostRelayJob from Async(default) in 3.66ms

Rendering posts/create.js.erb
Rendered posts/_list.html.erb (7.5ms)
Rendered posts/create.js.erb (9.0ms)
```

However the post in the other browser doesn't update, I'm pretty new to rails so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior arises on the circumstance that you are **creating your Post object within your Rails console**. It heavily depends on your ActionCable configuration but I think you are not using Redis in your development environment.

The default configuration for development environments is to use the `async` adapter. This adapter only works within the same process. To enable cross-process communication you would need an alternate adapter.

My suggestion would be to install Redis (e.g. via `brew redis`), start it with `redis-server` and to update your config/cable.yml with:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems you are passing in the entire list instead of just appending each new item. If you want to do it the way you are doing it, I believe your problem is in your JS. You need to jQuery delete your old list and jQuery add your new list. You can do so by creating a container for your list like so:

```
<div id="list-container">
  Whatever HTML has the id "list" here
</div>
```

Then when you receive data:

```
received: function(data) {
// Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
console.log(data)
$('#list').remove
$('#list-container').append(data)
}
```